# How to fix 'cannot open source file "sys/ipc.h","sys/shm.h" ' in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, ipc, header-files, shared-memory

I have been trying to learn about IPC and shared memory basics. I am using Visual Studio Code(1.69.2), and I tried to run the code given below. Although I have installed all the necessary files required to run a C/C++ code ,which includes complete mingw setup, and yet the compiler says cannot open source file :
"sys/ipc.h" and "sys/shm.h".

I have added the header files as:

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
```

In this the error is only shown for "sys/ipc.h" and "sys/shm.h"

The code for IPC(which I used)

```html
int shared_sender(){

    void *shared_memory;
    char buff[100];
    int shmid;

    //get the shm id  for the process
    shmid=shmget((key_t)123,1024,0666|IPC_CREAT);
    printf("The shared memory id is %d\n",shmid);

    //allocate the memory or attach or store the shmid in the shared memory block
    shared_memory=shmat(shmid,NULL,0);
    printf("The shared memory location is %p\n",shared_memory);

    //take inout form user and store it in the shared memory block
    read(0,buff,100); //read from index 0 to 100 in buff
    strcpy(shared_memory,buff);  //copy value from buff to block
    printf("The value entered is : %s\n",(char*)shared_memory);

}
```

How do I  run this code using the header files as mentioned in compiler?

Comment: Sounds like you're using Windows. Windows doesn't have those old SysV IPC functions. Or the newer POSIX ones you should be using instead on Unix/Linux. It does its own thing instead.

Comment: Thank you Shawn, but is there any way to do in Windows?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory